# Is it necessary to check init state in flyweight pattern?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Here is an example from some python book:

```
import weakref
class CarModel:
    _models = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def __new__(cls, model_name, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        :type model_name: str
        """
        model = cls._models.get(model_name)
        if not model:
            model = super().__new__(cls)
            cls._models[model_name] = model
        return model

    def __init__(self, model_name, air=False, tilt=False, cruise_control=False, power_locks=False, alloy_wheels=False, usb_charger=False):
        if not hasattr(self, "initted"):
            self.model_name = model_name
            self.air = air
            self.tilt = tilt
            self.cruise_control = cruise_control
            self.power_locks = power_locks
            self.alloy_wheels = alloy_wheels
            self.usb_charger = usb_charger
            self.initted = True

    def check_serial(self, serial_number):
        print("{0} not yet available on {1}".format(serial_number, self.model_name))
```

Is it really necessary to check whether the object has been initialised? As far as I can see, the `__init__` function will be called only once anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a strange case because it's overriding __new__ so that it tracks different models of cars in a repository.

So you can do:

```
c = CarModel('ford')
<cars.CarModel at 0x7fb39dfc1be0>

c = CarModel('vw')
<cars.CarModel at 0x7fb39df72668>

c = CarModel('ford')
<cars.CarModel at 0x7fb39dfc1be0>
```

Notice how the second call to `CarModel('ford')` actually returns the *same object* (0x7fb39dfc1be0)? __new__ holds the repository of all the cars of different models and if you create a car with the same model name you used before you'll just get a copy of the old one back.

One thing to note about this is that the extra arguments you pass in the 2nd time are totally ignored (because it fails the `not hasattr(self, "initted")` test).